# Express JS route continues to execute endlessly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I am new to Express JS and Node in general, and I am having a slight problem here that I don't understand its reason.

So basically, this is my code for index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Continuous message!");
    res.send("Hello World");
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
)
```

Everything works great except for one thing. In my console the message "Continuous message!" keeps showing up endlessly in my console. Am I doing anything wrong here? Or is this the normal behavior here?

Thank you!

**Update**: the reason turned out to be the redirection from port 80 to port 3000. So I edited server's `site-available`  and the repetition no longer occurs. Question is now, how do I configure my AWS EC2 server to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 3000 without previous problem?

Update: I tried the EC2 Load Balancer and `iptables` commands. The problem is still there. Console messages and route code continues to execute every like 5 seconds. Which causes problems with my code flow.

Comment: With that piece of code alone it is impossible you hit the route `/` endlessly. So you might be doing something else wrong. The only thing is that any time you refresh or load `http://localhost:3000/` the `console.log` message will be printed.

Comment: I have my server configured to redirect all port 80 traffic to port 3000. Can this be any related to the situation here?

Comment: Seems like a good suspicion. If you are getting hit in the 80 port continuosly and you make a redirection to your Express server, that means you are loading the `/` endpoint getting the message logged.

Comment: so I typed the address with port 3000 in the browser and it also kept logging the same message in console. Any suggestions?

Comment: If that's all the code you have, then you were getting traffic constantly to port 80, which just means the app was doing its job, unless I"m missing something...?

Comment: no, the app link is private, so I don't think there is public traffic

Comment: If you're completely changing your question to that last edit, then I'd suggest you delete this question and post a new question.  To people reading your question now, they are confused about what you're really asking and the title doesn't match what you're asking.

Comment: Are you usng a load balancer? If so directing public traffic to 80 to the EC2 instance port 3000 should be easyl

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem is still the same. I keep getting endless execution.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I tried it and got the same problem.